# How to enforce key-range locking

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking, sql-server-2014

I have a table with a `CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY` made by the following fields:

```
| Group |  ID  | Other non-key fields...
|   A   |   1  |   foo
|   A   |   2  |   bar
|   B   |   1  |   so
```

I always access this table filtering by a specific Group value (`WHERE Group = @Something`).
I know that only 1 client can access each group (because it creates it, and no other clients know which other groups exists) so my question is: Is there a way to garantee concurrent access to the table, given the fact that the table is always accessed by the Group Column and only one client works on one Group?

I've looked around and I saw that `SERIALIZABLE ISOLATION LEVEL` allows Key-Range Locking, but every way I try it, I always fail.

I've setup 2 Management Studio tabs, each one with the same code, just different Group value (`A` in this example, `B` in the other tab)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Group = 'A'
GO
UPDATE MyTable
SET AField = 'something'
WHERE Group = 'A'

--ROLLBACK
```

The fact is that the first transaction I run, that locks everything, and stops the other one to even read the data from the table.

So how those Key-Range Locks works?
Is it even possible to obtain what I'm asking for?

Other things I tried:

- `ROWLOCK` hint. Doesn't work, also on MSDN pages, I've found that `ROWLOCK` hint does not block a lock escalation to the table level.
- `1211` trace flag for disabling lock escalation. Doesn't work either (it actually disable the lock escalation to the table level, but that does not change anything).
- Looking for groups very far away from each other. (maybe there were some pages in common... I don't know)

Comment: Have you considered partitioning to ensure that each Group is actually a separate table?

Comment: @MatBailie That could be a thing, I never tought about that. Do I just need to partition the table and nothing else?

Comment: You'll need to look into that yourself I'm afraid.  Not used SQL-Server in years.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is due to the fact that your key is a composite key including 3 different fields and you are only selecting on one of those fields.  If you truly want to prevent another session from updating data you are currently reading then within your transaction issue an **UPDLOCK**.  This will BLOCK other sessions from reading these records until your transaction is committed or rolled back.  This also doesn't have the nasty effect that a ROWLOCK has, which is where it often will escalate to a TABLE LOCK, causing DEADLOCKS.  An UPDLOCK will cause BLOCKING not DEADLOCKING.

Comment: My objective is to *only* lock rows i'm updating. I'll try tomorrow if UPDLOCK is what I'm looking for.